# Java rounding int values depending on arithmetic result

Tags: java, math, floating-point, rounding, precision

Lets say I do some arithmetic computation (like division and then addition) on `int` values and then want to store the result in an `int` value as well.

How do I round values up that are greater than or equal to `x.5` and then round down when they are less than `x.5`?

So `11.5 = 12`
and `11.3 = 11`

Comment: Call `Math.round()`?

Answer (score 1):

The Java.Math library provides floor and ceiling functions.

```
   import Java.Math.*;

    System.out.println(Math.ceil(13.4)); // Prints 14
    System.out.println(Math.floor(13.4)); // Prints 13
```

There is also a rounding function provided in the same library

```
    System.out.println(Math.round(10.6)); // Prints 11
    System.out.println(Math.round(10.4)); // Prints 10
```